# Using iteration to show contents of fields in object c#

Tags: c#

I'm in the process of learning the basics of C# and exploring some uses for the foreach loop.
I have an object `address`, and was trying to iterate my way through it to show the contents of the various fields in the object.
Below is the output i got when running the code, followed by expected output.

The output i got was:

```
System.String Building
System.String Street
System.String City
System.String Region
```

Expected output:

```
C5

London
Camden
```

Is this possible to do in a manner similar to the code below?

```
    class Address
    {
        public string? Building;
        public string? Street=string.Empty;
        public string? City=string.Empty;
        public string? Region=string.Empty;
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Address address=new Address();
            address.Building="C5";
            address.Street=null;
            address.City="London";
            address.Region="Camden";  
            foreach (FieldInfo str in address.GetType().GetFields())
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{str}");
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks,
Frank

Comment: Note that it is more common and more typical to have *properties* rather than mere fields in classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[FieldInfo.GetValue(Object)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.fieldinfo.getvalue?view=net-5.0)

> When overridden in a derived class, returns the value of a field
> supported by a given object.

```
foreach (var info in address.GetType().GetFields())
   Console.WriteLine($"{info.GetValue(address) ?? "Null"}");
```

**Output**

```
C5
Null // Added the null because... well ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
London
Camden
```

**Notes**

- There are bunch of [binding flags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.bindingflags?view=net-5.0) that you should familiarize yourself with when performing this type of reflection.
- To stave off the next question, there is also [Type.GetProperties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getproperties?view=net-5.0)
- Reflection should only be used when there is no other way, 9 times out of 10 a problem can be solved without needing to invoke reflective methods, this becomes particularly important when working in *hot paths*, code maintenance, linking and tree shaking pre build optimizations

Comment: Thank you for your insights!  this question came about more out of stubborn curiosity, than an actual need. Will try to plod along at the pace my C# book sets for me....